# Uploading Stencil Theme - Server Error

Tags: bigcommerce

I had my Bundled Stencil theme uploaded although now the store has a Server Error.

If I change the theme to Cornerstone the store loads fine. ( *with no server error* )

I am not sure what the root cause of the problem is.

I did notice that the theme is loading my only variation within the config.json file ( "Light" variation ). I did not put any settings under this variation as I don't want to use any variation at all... just the theme as I am building it. I am not sure if this could cause a Server Error? Would putting my default settings under the Variation that's being loaded help?

Any suggestions of advice will help, needing to get this theme active!

Has anyone been able to build, bundle and have a Stencil theme activated?

Thanks all,

- Aaron

Comment: Aaron, can you provide a store url or something by which I can contact you buy to get more details? It sounds like you might've spoken to our technical support team.

Comment: Sure. the URL is http://printsaverepeat--intuit-sandbox.mybigcommerce.com/ ... it's a sandbox store for a client of ours. Elsa is our partner rep, she suggested I check here for answers. She will have my contact info etc. Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1):

I'm under the impression that activating a custom stencil theme is still not supported:

https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/bundling-and-submitting-a-theme

*See: Support for Custom Submissions Is Pending

You should check with BC support to see if they can enable it for your specific case

Comment: BC uploaded my Bundled theme for me, as the Documentation states we aren't able to upload on our own at this time.

They haven't provided much help on why my theme causes a Server Error and actually suggested I check here for an answer.

Comment: Ah ok. Maybe someone from BC will chime in then.